# the difference appearance of website when browsing on http and https

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, ssl, https

I have this website and when I test it on different browsers using http and https, it works same way for Chrome and Mozilla. But with IE, when I access over https, the page is messed up. For eg. the header image goes to side, the footer comes to middle and things like that. Does it mean IE renders controls in different way for http and https? How can I fix this, is there any setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a repro URL? What version of IE? Have you monitored your network traffic (e.g. with Fiddler) to ensure that all downloads are succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating the website to make sure it is W3C compliant?  Also, do you have a doctype declared?  I've found that IE will act strangely without a doctype.

W3C Validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The validation has errors. But the doc type was declared. Do you think it should pass w3c validation to work fine. Thanks for the tip tho.